# Suggest merging [pentaho-spoon] and [kettle] into [pentaho-data-integration]

Tags: support, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

May I suggest a tag merge of [pentaho-spoon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pentaho-spoon) into [pentaho-data-integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pentaho-data-integration) as the former is the main, and unique for most of the users, tool of the latter.

May I also suggest a merge of the tag [kettle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kettle) into [pentaho-data-integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pentaho-data-integration) as the former is the old SourceForge name of the new brand name of the latter.

Comment: There is also [tag:pdi]. Also [kettle] mentions that it is for the Community Edition, whereas the [pentaho-data-integration] mentions that it is for all versions.  This needs more research than what has already been done.

Comment: The difference between the CE and the EE is so minute, it would be wiser to call everything the same, and specify when you speak about EE. Specify in the question, not in the tag.

Comment: Additionally, with an EE you have support, so no need for SOF. I could not found any PDI question relating to EE specific in SOF.

Comment: Can you [check these 88 posts out of 1250](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=1&tab=Relevance&q=%5bkettle%5d%20-%5bpentaho%5d%20-%5bpentaho-data-integration%5d%20-%5bpdi%5d%20-%22pentaho%22%20is%3aq%20-%22spoon%22%20-%22pdi%22&mixed=0), and make sure that they are related to pentaho? A simple look at the search excerpt is fine, you needn't go into the details. This is to make sure that no one else is using the kettle tag for some other tool/technology.

Comment: They are all related for sure to Pentaho Data Integrator/Kettle, except for 2 that may be related or not.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921787/libformulaerrorvalue-error-code-504) is more related to Pentaho Report Designer. But Kettle may call the PRD.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25173088/jsonpath-stopper) is more related to JSONparse. But it a common task for Kettle.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will try to move forward with this as soon as I can.